# Select employees who have NOT completed all training

Tags: ms-access

I'm not a frequent DBA, but I'm working on something to track training complete for some employees and I'm a bit stuck.  I'm using MICROSOFT ACCESS and have 3 tables:

```
           Employees
Last_Name (PK) | First_Name (PK)
     ----------+-----------
         Smith | Bob
         Bee   | Susy
...

          Training 
Training_Code (PK) | Description
     --------------+-----------
           001.001 | Orientation
           001.002 | Fundamentals of Stuff
...

        Completed Training (many-to-many)
Last_Name (FK)| First_Name (FK) | Training Code (FK) | Completion Date
    ----------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------
        Smith |       Bob       |       001.001      | 8/25/2022
        Smith |       Bob       |       001.002      | 8/25/2022
        Bee   |       Susy      |       001.001      | 8/25/2022 
        Bee   |       Susy      |       001.002      | 8/25/2022 
...
```

My goal is to simply write a query that returns all employees who have NOT completed all their training.  To do this, my plan was to query the `Employees` table and then do subqueries to count all the entries for a given employee in the `Completed_Training` table.
Finally, I'd count the total number of rows in the `Training` table.  If an employee has completed all training available, then the two numbers would match and the query SHOULD NOT return their name in the result.  My best attempt goes something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE (COUNT(SELECT * FROM Completed_Training WHERE Completed_Training.Last_Name = Employees.Last_Name)) < (COUNT(SELECT * FROM Training));
```

I get the error, `Cannot have aggregate function in WHERE clause (COUNT()<).`
However, I'm clearly not conceptualizing this right.  Can anyone where point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: ??? Subj: *.. who have completed all training*. Q: *.. who have NOT completed all their training*.

Comment: Provide tables structures - especially their primary keys and unique constraints.

Comment: Updated title and primary/foreign keys.  Checked the "suggestions" link and couldn't find my solution.  Not sure constraints are relevant here, but everything is "short text" except the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea whether it works in ms-access:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM "Completed Training"
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "Training Code") < ( SELECT COUNT(1)
                                           FROM Training );
```

The idea is to count the number of distinct training codes for each employee and compare it with the number of availible training codes.

This will work fine for most situations, however, employees that have not taken any training at all will not be reported. An alternative (simplified setup):

```
select name
from employees e
where exists (
    select 1 from training t
    where not exists (
         select 1 from completed_training ct
         where ct.name = e.name
         and ct.training_code = t.training_code
    )
);
```

The idea in the latter one is to check if there exists a traning such that the employee have not trained on it.

I have added a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ef754691414a22a70e76bca23495ea1a) for postgres with both these querys and a third query that subtracts completed_trainings from the cartesian product between employees and trainings.

Comment: This worked, thanks!  Only I didn't need "DISTINCT" since training_code is a unique FK anyways.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Cerkoryn, there's actually a glitch in my answer (an employee that have not had any practise at all). I have updated my answer with an alternative

Comment: Beautiful!  Works like a charm!  Thank you!!!